# Position and Size

Tags: html, css

I want to keep position and size of a link Image, something like this:

```
<a href="any link"><img src="any image" alt="any name"></a>
```

How do I make them keep their size and position on different display sizes?

Comment: Your question is very broad. Why would your image size change on different displays? Position with respect to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap these in a div and do it with CSS. Set the `height` and `width.` You can make the position permanent with `absolute.`  I added a red border to illustrate. you can view codepen also: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LMqyXN

You can specify the position with px and it will not move at all, or use % to make it scale with view.

```css
   .static {
border: solid;
  border-color: red;
  height: 35px;
  width: 85px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="static">
  <a href="any link"><img src="any image" alt="any name"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that but it keeps moving when it changes to a different size of display

Comment: Im checking it on Chrome´s device toolbar

Comment: @DefengHu if you dont want it to move, use px instead of %

Answer (score 0):

Use the vw and vh units like this:

```css
#id-of-image {
  width: 5vw;
  height 5vw;
}
```

```html
<a href="link"><img id="id-of-image" src="file" alt="text"></a>
```

vw is 1% of the width of the screen.

vh is 1% of the height of the screen.

List of css units:
[www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp)

Comment: what? i dont understand

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain well

Comment: I changed it, tell me if you still don't understand